# Japanese characters in authentication response attributes are rturned as question marks

Tags: spring-saml

So authentication response in Spring Security Saml Sample application looks like the following (the attribute value is question marks):

```
<saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_670fb4839b61c1398a1acb39e56ee5e6" ..>
    <saml2:AttributeStatement>
        <saml2:Attribute FriendlyName="userName" Name="urn:com.example:userName"
                         NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
            <saml2:AttributeValue>???????</saml2:AttributeValue>
        </saml2:Attribute>
 </saml2:Assertion>
```

I am using Shibboleth as IdP, and in the logs of IdP I see that authentication response xml (before encryption) holds actual values, not question marks.

Any idea how to read them properly? Or to check where they get scrambled.

*UPDATE #1 (2016-03-03)*

I disabled encryption of saml assertions temporarily, analyzed HTTP traffic between IdP and SP, and I see that Japanese characters arrive normally to browser in the authentication response. This proves that Spring Security Saml Sample fails to decode / display them properly. I will keep looking into ways to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is to add

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

To index.jsp of Spring Security Saml Sample application to make page Japanese characters display properly. :)